# Range scope inside worksheet_change functiion

Tags: excel, vba

This is the top of a Worksheet_Change function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Column offset
useroffset = Sheets("Data Sources").Range("L5").Value
useroffset = Range("User_Offset").Value
```

The first call works but the second doesn't even though "User_Offset" refers to the same cell

I get the error Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

What am I missing?

Comment: We need more info to go on than this. What line gives you the error? Do you have a range named "User_Offset"?

Comment: User_Offset refers to 'Data Sources"!$L$5.  The first call to useroffset works but the second, using the named range, doesn't.

I just tried it with a new spreadsheet and just these two lines of code and got the same error

Comment: Also, you didn't answer kyle's question. You have a `variable` called `useroffset` which you're assigning a value from `Sheets("Data Sources")...`, You also use a *named range* on the next line: `Range("User_Offset")`. Does that *name* exist in the workbook?

Comment: In which worksheet is this code placed? If it's on any sheet other than `Data Sources`, you'll get an error, because `Range` (unless otherwise qualified) always means `ActiveSheet.Range`, so you're doing `ActiveSheet.Range("Data Sources!$L$5")`

Comment: Try `useroffset = Application.Range("User_Offset").Value`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is worksheet reference missing, so just add it! ;)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Column offset
useroffset = Sheets("Data Sources").Range("L5").Value
useroffset = Sheets("Data Sources").Range("User_Offset").Value
```